Calderón–Zygmund/$L^p$ estimates for the linear heat equation
Let $C_r$ denote the open cylinder
$$
C_r = \{(x,t) \in \mathbb R^{n+1} : |x| < r, -r^2 < t < 0\}
$$
and consider a classical $C^{2,1}_{x,t}(C_1)$-solution to the linear heat equation
$$
\partial_t u - \Delta u = f(x,t), \quad (x,t) \in C_1
$$
where $f \in C^0(C_1)$.
If $f$ is $C^0(\overline{C_1}) \cap C^{\alpha,\alpha/2}(C_1)$, then the usual Schauder estimates state that
$$
\lVert D^2_x u\rVert_{L^{\infty}_{x,t}(C_{1/2})}+[D^2_x u]_{\alpha,\alpha/2,C_{1/2}} \leq C\left( [f]_{\alpha,\alpha/2,C_1} + \lVert u\rVert_{L^{\infty}_{x,t}(C_1)} \right) .
$$
Observe that we are estimating the full second-derivative, not only the Laplacian. A self-contained proof is possible using the blow-up argument from J. Simon (see these notes from S. Picard for example). First, prove the global Schauder estimates on $\mathbb R^n \times (-\infty,0]$ using a proof by contradiction, and then localize this estimate.
I'm looking for a self-contained proof of the Calderón–Zygmund/$L^p$-estimates, i.e. if $f \in C^0(C_1) \cap L^p(C_1)$, $2 \leq p < +\infty$, then
$$
\lVert D^2_x u\rVert_{L^{p}_{x,t}(C_{1/2})} \leq C\left( \lVert f\rVert_{L^p_{x,t}(C_{1})} + \lVert u\rVert_{L^{p}_{x,t}(C_1)} \right) 
$$
or something similar. In the time-independent case (i.e. for Laplace equation), those are called Calderón–Zygmund estimates. They can be obtained (see these notes from J. Sanpera for example) by interpolating a $L^2$ and a ${\operatorname{BMO}}/L^{\infty}$ estimate which are quite straightforward to obtain. I'm looking for a self-contained proof of the analogous estimates for the heat equation.
The standard reference is "Linear and Quasilinear Equations of Parabolic Type" by Ladyzenskaja but it is quite difficult to read and not very concise.

This is not a complete answer.
I've been searching for this kind of reference few months ago (see this post of mine).
Here is what I have collected.
In these notes you have a multiplier approach (using Mikhlin's Theorem), for the whole space. The same strategy is more or less proposed in the appendix of this book.
For a more direct approach (still the whole space), relying on the (anisotropic) Calderón–Zygmund decomposition, you can also check pages 64–65 of this book ; this last reference is comprehensive but  really dense.
I ended up rewriting what I needed (for the periodic case) in Section 3.5 of these lecture notes (in french, with vanishing initial datum).
I believe the estimate you're searching for should follow from the previous literature by localization (since you pass from $C_{1/2}$ to $C_1$ this should be doable). However, concerning the initial datum I expect something different involving a Sobolev norm of $e^{t\Delta}u(0)$, which should translate into some Besov norm (see the first reference above).

Thanks for these references. I'll look at the books you suggested. I just wanted to mention that my question differs slightly from yours as I'm trying to estimate all the second-order derivatives, not only the Laplacian.

Oh you're right ! But doesn't this means that using the laplacian case, your question reduces to the pure elliptic estimate (from laplacian to all cross derivatives) ?

Oh yeah, you are right. I was worried about the time variable, but this does not seem to be an issue after all. You can integrate the elliptic estimate $$||D^2_x u(\cdot,t)||{L^p(B{1/4})}^p \lesssim ||u(\cdot,t)||{L^p(B{1/2})}^p+||\Delta u(\cdot,t)||{L^p(B{1/2})}^p$$ and it should work just fine. I'll look carefully at your references, then !

In this very recent preprint by Lewenstein-Sanpera and Ros-Oton, they prove the Calderón–Zygmund estimates by contradiction-compactness: $L^p$ estimates for the Laplacian via blow-up. It is short and self-contained.
